# Passing DISPPARAMS

Tags: com, parameter-passing

I'm unit testing a function with the following signature,

```
void foo(DISPPARAMS* pDispParams, VARIANT* pVarResult)
```

I need to pass this `pDispParams` from outside, pointing to the mock type I have at hand. I'm creating the mock types using GMock.

I create a mock object locally on the stack and try to pass it around like so,

```
Mock_Item mock_Item; //my mock type on which I would like to set expectations

DISPPARAMS dp = { nullptr, nullptr, 0, 0 };
VARIANT *args = new VARIANT[1];
VariantInit(&args[0]);
args[0].vt = VT_DISPATCH;
args[0].pdispVal = &mock_Item;
dp.rgvarg = args;
dp.cArgs = 1;
```

`foo`, internally does the following,

```
IDispatch* pCtrl(nullptr);
```

and tries to get the value out of the `pDispParams` passed to it

```
if (pDispParams != nullptr && 
pDispParams->rgvarg != nullptr && 
VT_DISPATCH == pDispParams->rgvarg[1].vt)
        pCtrl = pDispParams->rgvarg[1].pdispVal;
```

but with this `pCtrl` always turns out to be `nullptr`. I'm not very good at using these types related to COM. **How should I populate the `VARIANT` and  `DISPPARAMS` so that `pCtrl` will point to my mock object correctly ?** In particular, it appears to me that, the condition (`VT_DISPATCH == pDispParams->rgvarg[1].vt`) fails, as I see in the debugger's watch window. It has a value that is not `9`(`VT_DISPATCH`). `Mock_Item` is derived from `IDispatch` as you might have guessed.

Answer (score 1):

`new`ing up the object seems to work. TBH, I don't know what's going on.

```
CComPtr<Mock_Item> mock_Item = new Mock_Item;
...
dp.rgvarg[1].pdispVal = mock_Item;
dp.rgvarg[1].vt = VT_DISPATCH;
```

Comment: That only works by accident, you are supposed to call QueryInterface to get the IDispatch interface pointer.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. I'm not sure what is it that you mean exactly. However, `foo` seems to query for a different interface. (it is doesn't seem to call `QueryInterface` explicit but there is some casting that appears to do this internally.) i.e, the following expectation is satisfied.  `const IID iid_Item = __uuidof(_productionItem); EXPECT_CALL(*mock_Item, QueryInterface(_productionItem, _)).Times(1).WillOnce(DoAll(SetArgPointee<1>(&mock_Item), Return(S_OK)));` Would be helpful for me if you can explain in simpler terms.

Comment: @HansPassant I think I've understand what were you expecting me to have done. This assignment  `dp.rgvarg[1].pdispVal = mock_Item;`, should not happen like this but I should query for `IDispatch` interface and assign that instead. Have I understood correctly ? If yes, how should I do that exactly ?